# Calculating exp(x) with the use of recursion in Python

Tags: python, math, recursion, exp

I'm attempting to calculate e^x using recursion, e^x = e^(x/2)*e^(x/2), and the third order [Maclaurin expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for e^x and the script keeps returning 1. I'm not looking for a higher accuracy solution, just simply to understand where the script goes wrong : )

My thought is that with enough iterations it should end up with (1+x/N+(x/N)^2/2)^N when the function value goes below the limit.

```
def exp(x):
      if abs(x)<0.0001:
            return 1+x+x**2/2
      else:
            y=exp(x/2)
            return y*y
```

Comment: put 
`from __future__ import division` at the top of your script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead (note the `2.0` in the recursive call):

```
def exp(x):
    if abs(x) < 0.0001:
        return 1 + x + x**2 / 2.0
    else:
        y = exp(x / 2.0)
        return y * y
```

It is failing because if you pass an integer in for `x`, say `1`, then `x / 2` does integer division (in python 2.x), which would result in `0` instead of `0.5`. By using `x / 2.0`, it forces python to use float division.

Comment: Note that this is only a problem in Python 2.  In 3.x, `/` always means true division, regardless of operands.

Comment: Note that I updated the other division (in the `if`). Without that, it would not have worked for x=0, because it would never have gotten to the else clause, which converts it to a float. Thus it would have returned `0` for `exp(0)` which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

```
def exp(x):
    if abs(x)<0.0001:
        return 1+x+(x**2)/2.0
    else:
        y=exp(x/2.0)
        return y*y
```

Integer division truncates. You need floats here.